# Angularjs ng-repeat formating into cells

Tags: angularjs

I want to achieve something like this using `ng-repeat`. Using `<table>` but Im stuck.

```
instrument1 instrument4 instrument7 instrument10
instrument2 instrument5 instrument8 instrument11
instrument3 instrument6 instrument9 instrument12
```

Here is my code..

```
    <table>
        <tr  class="instrument" ng-repeat="instrument in instrumentCodes">
            <td>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    name="selectedInstruments[]"
                    value="{{instrument}}"
                    ng-checked="selection.indexOf(instrument) > -1"
                    ng-click="select(instrument)"
                > {{instrument}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I want this :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>instrument1</td>
        <td>instrument4</td>
        <td>instrument7</td>
        <td>instrument10</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>instrument2</td>
        <td>instrument5</td>
        <td>instrument8</td>
        <td>instrument11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>instrument3</td>
        <td>instrument6</td>
        <td>instrument9</td>
        <td>instrument12</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Some help would be very appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand what it is exactly the problem you're trying to solve. Is the current code not working at all, or are you trying to do something else and this is your starting point? What is the structure of an instrument, is it a plain string?

Comment: This is the starting point. I want 3 "instruments" per columns. I have edited my question. The question is about getting the right format

Comment: You can put another tag which its style will starts a new row with this condition on it: ng-if="{{$index / 3 == 0}}". Note that you can also handle it purely with css (if it's all floating divs, nth child won't have a float). Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: I have tried it with ng-if="{{$index / 3 == 0}}" but it didn't work !

Comment: @haimlit Could you provide an example ?

Comment: Sorry, I had a few syntax and javascript errors (forgot that division in javascript won't necessarily give an integer). Here you go: http://plnkr.co/edit/g3nday9sXTLsE1HojhVJ?p=preview

Comment: Also, if you want the final structure to be a table, I think restructuring your data is more suitable. You will have an object with array for each row, and in the DOM you'll make two ng-repeats

Comment: Well I have actually used $index % 3 === 0 instead of / but inside the table <tr>. The result is it shows only 1 on 3 rows. Your solution seams to work but @zote's solution also and Im using it right now. Thanks for the time you take to answer :) Sweetie :)))) Funny guy !

Comment: Note that @zote's solution works only on fixed width text. If you want to go with pure css solution (which is fine) I recommend using floating divs or inline-block display, breaking by clear:both or display: block on the nth child.

Comment: You're right, but it fits my need as I know the with of each elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a parnet div width for example 120px width and add content divs to this with width = 40px;
This way, and you add 4th item, it'll be splited to another line.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Xhv6lOeQKg1Q3AOFmltB?p=preview

Comment: Thanks I will use your solution !